# In SQL Server 2000 how do you add {n} number of 0's to a nchar(n)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I'm using SQL Server 2000 and I'm not sure if there is already a function to add any number of 0's to an `nchar(n)`, or if this is best done in a function?

Does this look correct

```
  proc repeatingCh
     @n int, -- i/p n to some number of characters
     @ch nchar(1), --i/p character
     @ch_n nchar(n) out
  as
  begin
     declare @ch_n as nchar(n)
     set @ch_n = ''

     for(i=1 to n)
     begin
        @ch_n = @ch_n + @ch
     end

     return 1
  end
```

I want to call it in a sproc or... most likely a function and return the repeating characters.

Comment: If your n is larger than 5, I would strongly recommend using `NVARCHAR` instead of `NCHAR`. `NCHAR` fields will always be padded up to their defined length with spaces, so if you have a `NCHAR(50)` field and store `value` in it, you'll still have 50 characters (and 100 bytes) being used, even though your string is only 5 characters long

Answer (score 4, accepted):

me again ;)
You can use `REPLICATE` for this:

```
SELECT REPLICATE('0', 10)
```

Comment: Ahh great.  And I can probably just stick n where 10 is to get any number of '0's. thx

Comment: Yeah, sorry, should have used this in your original question. But I always forget that nice little `REPLICATE`

Comment: Now I can combine this with the previous question to create the function I need based on n number of digits, and some integer it will give me a digit with leading '0's with a total of n digits.

Answer (score 1):

ex
your record  is unsized
col1
55
66
777
888

you need all in 6 digit

if 
select replicate('0',6-len(col1))++col1

or

declare @input varchar(10)

set @input = '1234'

select replicate('0',10-len(@input))++@input